# Question on a consequence of Artin's holomorphy conjecture

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Under Artin's holomorphy conjecture we can say, for any finite extension $K/F$ of number fields $\frac{\zeta_K(s)}{\zeta_F(s)}$ is entire. Here is a proof:

Let $\overline{K}$ be normal closure of $K$ over $F$. Say $G=\mbox{Gal}(\overline{K} /F)$ and $H=\mbox{Ga}l(\overline{K} /K)$. Clearly both of $G$ and $H$ are finite Galois extensions. Yes, we will take advantage of this. First of all note that,
$$L(s, \mbox{Ind}_H^G(1_H),\overline{K}/K)=L(s, 1_{H}, \overline{K}/K)=\zeta_K(s)$$
\noindent We can write 
$$\mbox{Ind}_H^G(1_H)=1_G+\sum_{\chi \in \mbox{Irr}(G),\chi \neq 1} a_{\chi}\chi$$
\noindent From Frobenius reciprocity it follows, $1_G$ is coming with multiplicity one. And also $a_{\chi}$'s are non-negative as they are multiplicity of $\chi$ in $\mbox{Ind}_H^G(1_H)$. So we get
$$L(s, \mbox{Ind}_H^G(1_H),\overline{K}/K)=\zeta_F(s)\prod_{\chi \neq 1}L(s,\chi,K)^{a_{\chi}} =\zeta_K(s)$$
where $a_{\chi}$'s are all non negative. Artin's conjecture does rest of the job.

A recent expository note by K. Murty and Foote (see [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2015-52-03/S0273-0979-2015-01492-8/S0273-0979-2015-01492-8.pdf) at page 474) says , under Artin conjecture $$\frac{\zeta_{K_1K_1}(s)\zeta_{K_1\cap K_2}(s)}{\zeta_{K_1}(s)\zeta_{K_2}(s)}$$
is entire. I am not understanding how to prove this. Could anyone please explain ?

Source of the paper: 
*Foote, Richard; Ginsberg, Hy; Murty, Vijaya Kumar*, [**Heilbronn characters.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/bull/1492), Bull. Am. Math. Soc., New Ser. 52, No. 3, 465-496 (2015). [ZBL1326.20007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1326.20007).

Comment: The quotient of $\frac{\zeta_{K_1K_2}(s)}{\zeta_{K_1}(s)}$ by $\frac{\zeta_{K_2}(s)}{\zeta_{K_1\cap K_2}(s)}$ is meromorphic, under Artin's conjecture. But under the right Galois hypothesis, $\zeta_{K_2}$ should be a factor of $\zeta_{K_1K_2}$, so that the quotient is actually holomorphic (the zeros of the denominator cancel witht the zeros of the numerator, with multiplicities).

Comment: I have found a reference of proof, it is given as a lemma in Stark's paper on effective Brauer-Siegel theorem.

Comment: I see. Lemma 12 [here](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN356556735_0023?tify={%22pages%22:[157],%22panX%22:0.574,%22panY%22:0.687,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.515}).